# How do I add another Stack Exchange OpenID to my account?

Tags: support, login, stack-exchange-openid

I want to add a new Stack Exchange OpenID (with a different email address) to my Stack Exchange account, but it isn't working. I can click <kbd>add new login</kbd>, but when I select <kbd>log in with Stack Exchange</kbd> it just takes me back to the homepage without doing anything. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to do with how Stack Exchange OpenID works. Whether or not you're logged in to SE is independent from whether or not you're logged in to SE OpenID. What happens when you select <kbd>log in with Stack Exchange</kbd> is that SE asks SE OpenID if somebody's logged in, and SE OpenID says "yeah, this OpenID's logged in", and SE then looks up which SE account that OpenID corresponds to.

In order to successfully add a second SE OpenID account, you'll need to visit https://openid.stackexchange.com/ and log out, then log in as (or register) the second OpenID. Once you've done that, the <kbd>log in with Stack Exchange</kbd> button back on SE will produce the expected result of asking you whether you really want to associate that OpenID with your account - confirm, and you'll have two SE OpenIDs.